# Посчитать кол-во цифр в числе и сложить их

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Думал, как применить while, но ничего так и не придумал. Остановился на этом. Есть вариант перевести строку в список, после расставить между каждым первым элементом пробелы, задать `split(' ')`, а после просуммировать. Проблема в том, что не знаю, как это реализовать.

```
    number = input('Введите число: ')
    num = len(number)
    print (f'\nКол-во цифр = {num}')

    if num == 2:
        answer = int(number[0]) + int(number[1])
        print (f'Сумма чисел = {answer}')
    elif num == 3:
       answer = int(number[0]) + int(number[1]) + int(number[2])
       print (f'Сумма чисел = {answer}')
    elif num == 4:
       answer = int(number[0]) + int(number[1]) + int(number[2]) + int(number[3])
       print (f'Сумма чисел = {answer}')
    elif num == 5:
       answer = int(number[0]) + int(number[1]) + int(number[2]) + int(number[3]) + int(number[4])
       print (f'Сумма чисел = {answer}')
    elif num == 6:
       answer = int(number[0]) + int(number[1]) + int(number[2]) + int(number[3]) + int(number[4]) + 
       int(number[5])
       print (f'Сумма чисел = {answer}')
    elif num == 7:
       answer = int(number[0]) + int(number[1]) + int(number[2]) + int(number[3]) + int(number[4]) + 
       int(number[5]) + int(number[6])
       print (f'Сумма чисел = {answer}')
    elif num == 8:
       answer = int(number[0]) + int(number[1]) + int(number[2]) + int(number[3]) + int(number[4]) + 
       int(number[5]) + int(number[6]) + int(number[7])
       print (f'Сумма чисел = {answer}')
    elif num == 9:
       answer = int(number[0]) + int(number[1]) + int(number[2]) + int(number[3]) + int(number[4]) + 
       int(number[5]) + int(number[6]) + int(number[7]) + int(number[8])  
       print (f'Сумма чисел = {answer}')
    elif num == 10:
       answer = int(number[0]) + int(number[1]) + int(number[2]) + int(number[3]) + int(number[4]) + 
       int(number[5]) + int(number[6]) + int(number[7]) + int(number[8]) + int(number[9])
       print (f'Сумма чисел = {answer}')
    elif num == 11:
       answer = int(number[0]) + int(number[1]) + int(number[2]) + int(number[3]) + int(number[4]) + 
       int(number[5]) + int(number[6]) + int(number[7]) + int(number[8]) + int(number[10])
       print (f'Сумма чисел = {answer}')
       else:
    print ('Мне тяжело это посчитать =)')
```

Comment: `sum(int(dig) for dig in str(number))`  или в функциональном стиле: `sum(map(int, number))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, тут даже я, не знающий Python, справлюсь :) Или я неверно понял задание?

```
number = int(input('Введите число: '))

num = 0
summ = 0
while(number):
   num = num + 1
   summ = summ + number % 10
   number = number // 10

print('Цифр ', num)
print('Сумма ', summ)
```

Для отрицательных чисел можно предусмотреть изменение знака, например..

Comment: Всё четко, спасибо) Я тормоз мальца

Answer (score 2):

Продолжил вашу мысль.Тут можно и без split обойтись.

```
numbers = [int(i) for i in input('число: ')]  # создаем список из того что ввели,каждый элемент в нем будет (int)
print('сумма цифер в числе: ', sum(numbers))  # печатаем сумму элементов в списке,то есть сумму всех цифер в числе
```